# Google Calendar API service: My calendars vs Other calendars and import.calendar.google.com vs group.calendar.google.com

Tags: calendar, synchronization, google-calendar-api, calcurse-caldav

**Problem description**

Using the [GAS-ICS-Sync](https://github.com/derekantrican/GAS-ICS-Sync) Apps script and the [Google Calendar API service](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/overview), returns a different `<CalendarID>` URL and goes under "My calendars" instead of "Other calendars" which does not work with [Calcurse-Caldav](https://www.calcurse.org/files/calcurse-caldav.html), which uses [Google’s Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/overview), failing with a 404 error!

**Question**

Is there a way to add the synced calendars using [Google Calendar API service](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/overview) under the “Other calendars” vs “My calendars”?

**Background**

I'm using ‘[calcurse-caldav](https://calcurse.org/files/calcurse-caldav.html)’ so that I can view my Calendar Schedules from the Command Line (macOS), which is part of my workflow and some terminal todo.txt apps I've written.

Since Google's default update schedule for subscribed calendars is about 1 day, I'm using the [GAS-ICS-Sync](https://github.com/derekantrican/GAS-ICS-Sync) Google Apps script to perform the sync update scheduling. When I subscribe to a calendar using “From URL”, Google puts it under “Other calendars” which works  with 'calcurse-caldav'. But when I use [GAS-ICS-Sync](https://github.com/derekantrican/GAS-ICS-Sync), the Google Apps script puts the calendar under "My calendars".

**Software**

1. [calcurse-caldav](https://calcurse.org/files/calcurse-caldav.html)
2. [GAS-ICS-Sync](https://github.com/derekantrican/GAS-ICS-Sync)
3. [Google Calendar API service](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/overview)

**Details**

Google CalDav API URL

```
[https://apidata.googleusercontent.com/caldav/v2/<CalendarID>/events/]
```

Your script is truly a God send but it puts the Calendar under “My Calendars” which gives a different CalendarID URL the for Subscribed calendars when working through the Google Calendar GUI. 'calcurse-cadav' then I get a http 404 error with the new URL.

CalendarID URLs

Other calendars:

```
/caldav/v2/e1jb65cfvjhh94esv69vd03tj5unhli0@**import**.calendar.google.com/events/
```

My calendars:

```
/caldav/v2/7cnlmnds2t57uqvr1g57iahaip@**group**.calendar.google.com/events/
```

Notice: Google returns a `CalendarID` with a URL subdomain of "import" for subscribed calendars under "Other calendars" and a URL subdomain prefix of "group" for calendars under "My calendars"

**Describe the solution you'd like**

I'd like to be able to modify the script so that the sync'ed / subscribed ics calendar is put under the "Other calendars" and given a subdomain prefix of "import..calendar.google.com".

Answer (score 0):

I believe ticking the calendar in question on this page:
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/syncselect

Will solve all your problems and make the calendar marked as "Other", accessible to all third party apps.